# Capacitor's Charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, units, unit-conversion

I see the formula of charge on capacitor's plate is $C=\frac{KA}{d}$, where $K$ is the dielectric constant and $A$ is the area of the capacitor. Now some sources indicate the unit of $A$ as square-inch whereas some other take $A$ as square-centimeter. Which one is correct?

Comment: K is unit-less, so it does not change. When is the US (along with Liberia and Myanmar) going to join the rest of the world and go metric?

Comment: Well still the question is how it affect the result of formula. Should I take A as square inch or square cm, the C (in farad) would not have the same value. So which sources are correct ?

Answer (score 0):

There are several different unit systems used for electrical quantities, but ***I have never seen any system of electrical units based on inches***. When you say "some sources indicate", make sure they are *reliable* sources before you believe what they say.

The only *standard* unit system for electrical quantities that is used today is SI units, which include the familiar volts, amperes, farads, henrys, etc.

In physics, there are (in the opinion of some physicists) advantages in using two different sets of units called "electrostatic units" (ESU) and "electromagnetic units" (EMU), because the "formulas" are simpler. Historically, both of these are based on the centimeter-gram-second units for mass length and time, not on the meter-kilogram-second SI units.

Historically, there was also a system called "Gaussian units" which can be described as "half ESU units and half EMU".

Old physics textbooks often use ESU, EMU, or Gaussian units, which can cause  beginners to get very confused.

This [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centimetre%E2%80%93gram%E2%80%93second_system_of_units#Derivation_of_CGS_units_in_electromagnetism) page has a summary of the relationships between the different unit systems.

Note that the "dielectric constant" $K$ in your formula is the *ratio* of the dielectric properties of a material to the properties of a vacuum, so it is dimensionless. However the "permittivity of a vacuum" $\epsilon_0$ is $1.0$ by definition in some of the unit systems, but not in others.

Most likely your formula "C = KA/d" used a units system where $\epsilon_0 = 1$, and so your formula does not include $\epsilon_0$.

Comment: Well it is true that most academic and references use metric system for calculation. However those sources that use area as square inch in nominator, take d (distance between plates) as inch in denominator. So by K being a constant, we may obtain same precision by different scale !

Answer (score 0):

In the electrostatic system of units (esu) the constant in Coulomb's law is set to be equal to one, with appropriate units, so $F = \frac{q_1 q_2}{r^2}$ which is equivalent to having $\frac {1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o} = 1$.

A consequence of that definition is that capacitance was often measured in centimetres which is easily seen if one notes that the capacitance of an isolated sphere is radius $a$ is given by $4 \pi \epsilon_o a$ in the SI system of units.
However this ignores the fact that the unit of charge in this system, the statCoulomb or just esu has the units of $\text{g}^{\frac 1 2} \text{cm}^{\frac 3 2 } \text{s}^{−1}$.
Some museums have example of such capacitors with capacitance measured in centimetres.

So the formula for the capacitance of a parallel plate arrangement in esu is $C = \dfrac{KA}{4 \pi d}$ with the centimetre as the unit of length and $K=1$ for a vacuum.

This formula could be adapted to become $C = \dfrac{K' A}{d}$ with lengths in centimetres and $K' = \dfrac {1}{4 \pi}$ for air with lengths measured in centimetres and $K'' = \dfrac {2.54 }{4 \pi}$ with lengths measured in inches.

Does your reference give you values of the dielectric constant of a vacuum/air?

Comment: Good question! In fact the table of Dielectric Constants are everywhere on Internet, but rarely they indicate the voltage break-down limit (per millimetre of thickness) -- used between capacitor's plate.

Answer (score 0):

$C=\frac{\kappa \epsilon_0 A}{d}$  where in MKS units
$$C=[Farads]$$
$$\kappa=relative \ permittivity=dielectric \ constant= [dimensionless]=1 \ for \ vacuum$$
$$\epsilon_0=permittivity \ of \ the \ vacuum=8.8 \times 10^{-12} \ [\frac{Farads}{meter}]$$
$$A=area \ of \ the \ plate \ [meters^2]$$
$$d=distance\ between \ the \ plates \ [meters]$$